# Python logger left align level with color + :

Tags: python, logging

I am using fastapi and uvicorn and I want my logger to look the same. I don't manage to do it.

The logging is as follows:

```
INFO:     Application startup complete.
WARNING:  StatReload detected changes in 'ethjsonrpc/main.py'. Reloading...
INFO:     Shutting down
INFO:     Waiting for application shutdown.
```

ie. left aligned, `:`, space up to 9 char, then message.
The INFO, WARNING, etc. are colored.

My best attempt so far is:

```
formatter = logging.Formatter("\033[32m%(levelname)s\033[0m: %(message)s")
handler = logging.StreamHandler()
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
logger.addHandler(handler)
```

but it produces unaligned double output

```
WARNING:  StatReload detected changes in 'ethjsonrpc/main.py'. Reloading...
INFO:     Shutting down
INFO:     Waiting for application shutdown.
INFO:     Application shutdown complete.
INFO:     Finished server process [67092]
INFO: ✅ Devnet running in background
INFO:ethjsonrpc.main:✅ Devnet running in background
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be something like this:

```
import uvicorn
import logging

FORMAT: str = "%(levelprefix)s %(asctime)s [%(threadName)s]  [%(name)s]  %(message)s"

logger = logging.getLogger("logger")
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
console_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
console_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
formatter = uvicorn.logging.DefaultFormatter(FORMAT, datefmt="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
console_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(console_handler)

logger.info("I'm logging")
logger.warning("some warnings")
```

I use `uvicorn.logging.DefaultFormatter` to get the default format

and the logs will be like this (of course the format will be different, up to you):
[image]

Comment: thanks, logs are doubled with this setting for me